# How do I set the Organization from the Employer Relationship as a contact's Current Employer for multiple contacts at once?

Tags: import, relationships

I have over 1,000 contacts which I imported along with an employer relationship, but these employers aren't showing up as "Current Employer" on the contact summary page because the relationship wasn't marked as current when it was created. I know how to fix this on an individual level, but not how to fix them all at once. Is there a way for me to make it so that all of these relationships are updated to "current employer" in a batch or mass update process, or do I have to do each one individually? Is there a way to indicate that this is the current employer when running an import?

CiviCRM 5.49.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

There are a few options. Is this an import to a new system, so can we assume that *all* employer relationships should be active?  If so, you could do:

- Go to `Support > Developer > Api Explorer v4`
- Select entity: 'Relationship', action: 'update'
- Where: select 'relationship_type_id:name', '=', 'Employee of'
- Values: 'is_active', 'yes'
- Execute

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this might work! I will have to look through and see if there's any reason to think we might have some old employer relationships in there that we don't want to have set as current. Would this impact new imports going forward?

Comment: No, this just changes existing relationships.  When you did the import, did you add them to a new group, or a new tag?

Comment: seems a bit of a gap that there is no feature on Import to let one set an Org to be their Current Employer

Comment: Yes, I added them to a group that already existed, and I gave them a new tag just for that day's import.